# Understanding this for-loop for scrolling maze game

Tags: python, for-loop

so I was making a simple "Navigate your cube through a maze" type game. Lookin around youtube, I found this neat bit of code that I could use to easily layout the maze for my game.

```
level1_map = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

So my window size is set to 600x800, since each block will be 50x50, there are 12 rows and 18 columns.

```
class Level():

def __init__(self,map):
    self.map = map
    self.blocklist = []

def createMap(self):
    for y in range(0,len(self.map)):
        for x in range(0,len(self.map[y])):
            if self.map[y][x] == 1:
                self.blocklist.append(Block(x*12,y*18))
```

^ My level class. btw, I have a Block class. 
Ok so the main problem is that I don't understand the previous chunk of code (the for loop). It works perfectly fine, but I want to make my game able to scroll and follow the cube, so I need to make the layout extend beyond my 600x800 window. The for loop doesn't seem to play with my window size, but when I try and add more rows/columns to my layout it doesn't add blocks beyond the window. It would be helpful if someone could explain the for loop to me and suggest an idea for my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: The for-loop is looping through the 2d map from your first snippet.  There are two loops, one for each axis (`x` & `y`).  Any time there is a 1 in the 2d map it will create a new block and add it to a list of blocks.  Try printing the value of `x` & `y` inside the if statement.  Also, try printing the list of blocks each time through the loop.  I don't know why adding more blocks doesn't adjust your window size, the code to control window size isn't posted.  My guess is that the window size (and any scroll bars) are not calculated from the block list but set some other way (e.g. hard-coded)

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I really appreciate it! As for the window size, I'll try and figure it out, now that I know how the for-loop works. Thanks again!